# Не выполняется блок Done в Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Всем привет. Есть код для загрузки изображения

```
$container.find('.async-upload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    start: function (e, data) {
      $(e.target).closest('.croppable-image-container').addClass('loading');
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
      var result = data.result,
        file = result.files[0],
        $target = $(e.target),
        $block = $target.closest('.croppable-image-container'),
        $err = $block.find('.async-upload-error');
      if (!result.success) {
        if (!file) {
          $err.html('При загрузке файла произошла ошибка');
        } else {
          $err.html(file.error);
        }
        $target.addClass('error');
        $err.show();
        $block.removeClass('loading');
      } else {
        $target.removeClass('error');
        $err.hide();
        updateCropContainer($block, file);
        if (result.copies) {
          for (var c in result.copies) {
            var $copyBlock=$('.croppable-image-container input[data-attribute="'+c+'"]').closest('.croppable-image-container'),
              copyFile=result.copies[c];
            updateCropContainer($copyBlock, copyFile);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Блок Start отрабатывает, а вот блок Done нет. В чем может быть причина? куда копать?

Comment: открыть надо дебаг значит и посмотреть

Comment: Добавьте fail: function (e, data) { console.log(data.errorThrown); }, ответ узнаете в консоли

Comment: @frozencoast SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 142
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSON (jquery.min.js:2)
    at On (jquery.min.js:2)
    at T (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: @frozencoast Вот такая ошибка, это в каком файле мне ее искать?

Comment: Это означает что сервер возвращает не JSON. Тогда посмотрите что конкретно он возвращает: console.log(data.jqXHR.responseText);